# Stuck in Xamarin welcome screen after editing UI

Tags: xamarin

[image: Picture of running splash screen]

Even after adding code to the project and cleaning/rebuilding the project I still see this, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You haven't shown us anything you've done so how can we say what you might be doing wrong?  Did you edit the existing XAML welcome page?  Or did you create a new page?  Did you update the App class to point to the new page?

Comment: I just edited the mainpage.xaml and added some code to a class which I represented in the mainpage.xaml.cs

Comment: try deleting the app from your device/emulator before deploying

Comment: worked thanks, is there any way to remove the numbers? it has like '000'  '016' still with a black borderbackground

Comment: that is an emulator setting